# Zend Studio 8 to 9 Upgrade (Mac OSX 10.6)

Tags: zend-studio

Since there is little information on how to upgrade from Zend Studio 8 to Zend Studio 9, I was wondering if someone had a recommended approach.

**My Goal**:

- To upgrade from Zend Studio 8.0.1 to Zend Studio 9.0
- To keep all (or at least most) of my current settings and definitely ***all of my files***

**Problems**:

- I have several projects checked out from SVN
- I have more than one workspace
- I *don't* have time to re-checkout from SVN on every project (but if it's the only way then so be it)

Anyway, I just want to know what to watch out for when it comes to bugs or issues with files/settings/workspaces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go ahead and install 9.0 without having to worry about loosing your Workspace Preferences. Once the installation is complete. Simply start Zend Studio and specify the same Workspace location(s) you were using before.

If I'm not mistaken workspace information is stored in the .metadata folder created by Zend Studio at the root of your workspace. When you specify your workspace in 9.0 Zend Studio will see this folder and any settings from the workspace while using 8.0 that are still available in 9.0 will still be in place.

As for your projects, if they're not automatically loaded into the workspace in the new version already, simply create a new project, and specify the existing folder of the old project. Zend Studio will see the .project file in the folder and tell you that a project already exists in the specified directory. This is ok, Zend will just attempt to load the old project and retain any project settings for that project.

I'm a bit rusty on the SVN portion. And I have had problems in the past when importing an existing project connected to an SVN Repository. If the Projects repository it is attached to is not already defined in your SVN Repositories view, Zend Studio will start barking at you stating that the project is attached to an unknown repository or something of the sort. If this happens... Well good luck getting it "re-attached" to the repository without just deleting the project and checking it out again entirely.

My advice is to have your SVN repositories setup BEFORE attempting to open any projects that you have connected to a Repo. Make sure to have the configuration all the same when re-setting up your repository definitions.

Good luck! & Gratz on the upgrade. Zend Studio rules.

Comment: Yeah I was actually half way through the process when I saw your answer. Thanks, you were _mostly_ right. (I didn't have to add any repositories this time, Zend Studio just sorta knew they were there or something).